# Pure ObjC (.m) vs ObjC & Cpp (.mm) mix

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios

Are there any pitfalls, when mixing Objective C & C++ in a .mm file, should I prefer sticking to just pure ObjC when possible?

Comment: Except where you are using or developing cross platform libraries in C++, I would question whether you need to use C++ at all.  Why introduce C++'s compromised object model when you already have Objective-C's much more "in the true spirit" model?

Answer (score 8):

Besides the caveats described in the Objective-C++ section of the Objective-C Programming Guide, there's nothing scary about Objective-C++. It takes a *lot* longer to compile than Objective-C, however and using C++ in a header infects any code that includes that header with the Objective-C++ requirement. So for your sanity, and the sanity of any clients of your code, use Objective-C when possible in "public" APIs and Objective-C++ when necessary.

Comment: I cannot stress the "watch the imports" part strong enough. I got countless meaningless errors until I finally switched that one .m into .mm.

Comment: Mostly agreed, but one can contain the infection with careful use of `#ifdef __cplusplus` in one's header files. For example, when declaring C++ objects as instance variables, one can use the `#ifdef` to declare them as `void*` when compiling as Objective-C, and `ClassName*` when compiling as Objective-C++.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure of any pitfalls that arise from using objective-C++ but I personally would recommend sticking to pure objective-c for clarity and code readability. If you are planning on using some specific C++ libraries then a nice way of going about using objective-C++ in your project would be keep all your C++ functionality in separate C++ class files, that way when you come to using your C++ objects in your .mm files, you can keep mixing up of obc-c and c++ code to a minimum. When I first started IOS dev I wrote a few projects using objective-C++, but the more I came to understand Cocoa and its power, I found the urge to use C++ dwindled as it is better and simpler just to stick with obj-c and the cocoa framework.